# basic ROR app working in terminal but not in netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, webrick

I have just created a basic rails app . It is working fine when I give `rails server` . But when I tried it in netbeans by creating a `Ruby on Rails Application from existing resources` and run the project , I am getting the following error

`could not connect to the webserver - cannon show http://localhost:3001`

`Output - WEBrick for myapp on 3001`

`/usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)`

I tried searching online based on the above error message , but It is of no use because , mine is having issue only when I run from netbeans .

Comment: what version of netbeans are you using ?

Comment: I guess ROR is supported in netbeans in higher versions of netbeans , try using 7.0 or lower version . Should work then.



Plus try installing rails manually once before downgrading.

 Tool -> Plugins -> "Available Plugins".. chek for "ruby on rails" and install it.

Comment: I have installed the necessary plugins , I can create a ruby application . My problem is creating a ROR application alone .

Comment: check the netbeans `ruby` version and also `rails` version did it match to your application `rails` ?

Comment: @RajarshiDas The rails version installed in my system is 4.0.0 . How to check the ruby version in netbeans ?

Comment: i do not want the rails version of your system please see my comments I want the rails version of your netbeans while you run your app it is asking to set rails version so what it is?

Comment: That's what I asked you , how to check the rails version of my netbeans